# How to do String.Copy in .net core?

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core

In porting a .net framework app to .net core app, there are some uses of [`String.Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.copy(v=vs.110).aspx) to copy strings. But it looks this method is removed from [.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.string), so how would you copy a string in .net core app, and as a result, it is not present in uwp too. Does assignment `string b = a;` in .net core means something different as in .netframework?

The copy is used in this code:

```
public DataDictionary(DataDictionary src)
        :this()
    {
        this.Messages = src.Messages;
        this.FieldsByName = src.FieldsByName;
        this.FieldsByTag = src.FieldsByTag;
        if (null != src.MajorVersion)
            this.MajorVersion = string.Copy(src.MajorVersion);
        if (null != src.MinorVersion)
            this.MinorVersion = string.Copy(src.MinorVersion);
        if (null != src.Version)
            this.Version = string.Copy(src.Version);
    }
```

Comment: Why would you use the `Copy` method?

Comment: No, it means just a reference copy in both cases. Do you know *why* the app is using `String.Copy`? It's pretty unusual to need ti, and is generally *worse* than using `=` (as it involves creating a copy in a way that is almost always unnecessary).

Comment: Related: [What's the use of System.String.Copy in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/520895/15498)

Comment: tried `new String(a)`?

Comment: @JonSkeet It's a user defined class with string members, and `string.Copy` was used in the copy constructor.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta The constructor `String(string) ` is not present in .net core too. :(

Comment: That doesn't explain *why* it's being used. Are you able to ask the original developer? It's possible that they didn't understand that strings are immutable in .NET. If they're really trying to ensure they have separate instances so they can lock on them or something similar, I would try to fix that poor practice...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the use of System.String.Copy in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520895/whats-the-use-of-system-string-copy-in-net)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assignment of a string is something else than creating a copy. `a = b` just sets the reference of both variables to the same memory segment. `string.Copy` actually copies the string and thus the references are not the same any more.

I doubt however if you need `string.Copy`. Why would you want to have another reference? I can't think of any common cases you ever want this ([unless you are using unmanaged code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/520949/993547)). Since strings are immutable, you can't just change the contents of the string, so copying is useless in that case.

---

Given your update with the code that uses `string.Copy`, I would say it is not useful to use `string.Copy`. Simple assignments will do if you use `DataDictionary` in managed code only.

Comment: Note that, [unlike JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41458001/why-to-avoid-creating-objects-in-javascript), `new String(new char[]{'a'}) == new String(new char[]{'a'})` is still `True`.

Comment: Due to interning I guess. That is the 'problem' `string.Copy` solves.

Comment: Bear in mind that string overrides [==](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality(v=vs.110).aspx) so it's not about interning.

Comment: Ah, of course. Good point @Damien_The_Unbeliever. (As a side question: why does `string.Copy` not work then?)

Comment: Thanks, in the code some members are assigned, some are copied, maybe I will just assign them all and see if any test breaks.

Comment: The correct answer, as answered by Kyle Stay below is `var copiedString = new string(stringToCopy.ToCharArray());`. There are valid instances where you want two different string instances of the same value. For example, unit testing code that may manipulate the memory of the string reference. It's rare, but valid.

Answer (score 19):

This is not as elegant as `string.Copy()`, but if you do not want reference equality for whatever reason, consider using:

```
string copiedString = new string(stringToCopy);
```

Comment: This was the first search result on Google when search for "string.copy c# .net core". Also, my answer does provider a solution the title question of "How to do String.Copy in .net core?".

Comment: Question itself not about the direct copying, but about the `Copy` method

Comment: So... I should have asked and then answered my own question?

Comment: Embedded in the "question" is "so how would you copy a string in .net core app". This answers that question. Your downvote is invalid.

Comment: This answers the question, should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

string newstring = $"{oldstring}";

Comment: Please consider explaining your code and how it helps resolve the question.

Comment: Copying any object is an inherently dangerous act. Normally when I want a copy of a string, I want an independent copy; one that, if I somehow change it, I don't change the thing I copied from.  String interpolation accomplishes this with the least amount of keystrokes.

Comment: I just tested this and the new string was still an object reference match with the old string however `string b = $"{a} ".Trim();` did work, but not with the space removed.